# dbt: are tables always rebuilt from scratch?

Tags: dbt

I am new to DBT and trying to figure out if it is the right fit for my application. I am using Postgres. In short, I have the following high-level workflow:

- data will be loaded into the `dbt_raw` schema
- a bunch of models will be used to transform the raw data into a series of tables in the `dbt_final` schema
- new data is added to the `dbt_raw` schema tables every day;
- the volume will eventually be in the hundreds of millions to single-digit billions of rows in the raw tables and about the same in the final tables
- in my production scenario, I would be exec'ing `dbt run ...` on a daily basis (after data is added to raw)

From what I can tell, it seems as though in order to go from raw to final, the *entire* data set is reprocessed. There is an "incremental" mode, but from what I can discern the way it works is basically an UPSERT, where it only inserts if the specified unique key doesn't already exist. That to me sounds like its still doing a total seq scan on the raw data every time I run `dbt run ...` even if it isn't necessarily inserting all those rows or rebuilding the table.

I've done some preliminary tests by putting a SERIAL column on an "incremental" table, set the sequence value manually and then done `dbt run...` to see whether the sequence was wiped out or preserved. It was wiped out.

But I somehow cannot believe that this is the case or that there isn't a work around.

*note: All of this is under the assumption that no schema has changed. That scenario is a question of its own...

I'd like to know:

1. Is this approach suitable given the expected table volume.
2. Am I doing it right/wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you already looked at this? https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/incremental-models#supported-incremental-strategies-by-adapter